# Hash problem in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I am newbie in Ruby.. seeking some help..

I have a code

```
DB = { 'key1' => "value1",
       'key2' => "value2"}

key = gets
DB["#{key}"]
```

when i enter `key1` from console i get `nil`
how to resolve this?

I tried few different alternative but could not solve it. hope to get help here.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a newline character at the end of your string. Use `gets.chomp` instead.

Comment: and you can just use DB[key] instead of DB["#{key}"]

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do? It is not completely clear in your question.

If you want to access the value in `DB` by entering the key I would do it like this:

```
DB = { 'key1' => "value1", 'key2' => "value2"}
key = gets.strip
puts DB[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, "key1" is just a string, like "value1".

If you want to pull "value1" out of DB using "key1", then all you need is

```
DB["key1"]
```

which will give you your "value1" back.

Comment: Ooh, most of us misunderstood the problem. Andy got it right. You're not getting the right value because the result from gets is not exactly "key1".

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's `gets` returns the value from the console including the newline character (\n). In practice, unless you need a newline to be on your input, get input with `var=gest.chomp`. `chomp` is a method of String the removes ending \n, \r, and \r\n characters. So your code would be this:

```
key=gets.chomp
puts DB[key]
```